# Pull down tableView programmatically

Tags: uitableview, ios5

I want to show  tableview's hidden headerview by pulling it down, delay for 1-2 seconds and back to the normal state programmatically.

Comment: My mac died 2 days ago, so I can't check. But what I think: You can use offsetContent, to set it to zero when viewDidAppear to see headerView, then wait 2 sec(GCD dispatch-after), then use scrollOffset(I don't remember the exact method name, you can find it in UIScrollViewDelegate) to scroll with animation to hide headerView.